# How to reduce time to wait for deploying webapp in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, deployment

Recently I've moved to Java Enterprise world. I use Netbeans IDE with Tomcat to develop my webapp. I faced a problem that it takes long time to deploy the webapp. When I change some code, netbeans requires re-deployment to make changes applied.

I did search around this problem and I found JRebel (which helps us apply code change quickly), but it is not free.

Can you tell me how to apply code changes quickly (freely)? And how to reduce deployment time in Netbeans?

Thank you very much,

Khuong Dao.